# Why UUID pattern is different in Linux or VM?

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine

when I run a command on VM.

```
[root@localhost:~] esxcli hardware platform get
Platform Information
   UUID: 0x39 0x33 0x38 0x35 0x37 0x31 0x47 0x53 0x48 0x31 0x33 0x33 0x58 0x33 0x48 0x42
```

When I run a Command on Linux and window. I got a pattern like

```
➜  frontend git:(master) sudo dmidecode -t 1 

System Information
    UUID: 86431C01-52BE-11CB-8375-B60E172FF8E3
```

Both VM UUID is in different Pattern. where [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) says

> In its canonical textual representation, the 16 octets of a UUID are
> represented as 32 hexadecimal (base-16) digits, displayed in 5 groups
> separated by hyphens, in the form 8-4-4-4-12 for a total of 36
> characters (32 alphanumeric characters and 4 hyphens). For example:
>
> 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000
>
> xxxxxxxx-xxxx-Mxxx-Nxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx

My Questions is

1. I'M getting a correct UUID?
2. UUID is different based OS (e.g Linux, VM, android, windows) or Based on a machine (Desktop, Laptop, Mobile, Server).
3. if it is different then how to validate?

Answer (score 0):

Both are same only representation are different here [full Article](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1880)

> In the virtual machine's configuration file, the UUID is stored under
> the "uuid.bios" key. The format separates the bytes with spaces and a
> hyphen. A sample UUID looks like this:
>
> 00 11 22 33 44 55 66 77-88 99 AA BB CC DD EE FF
>
> However, the format of the UUID is different when it is used as a
> virtual machine identifier in the /vm path hierarchy. There the UUID
> is presented in a format described in ISO 11578. In this format, the
> UUID has a different byte order, and several hyphens are used to
> separate some of the bytes. The sample UUID shown above would be
> reported in this format for ISO 11578 compatibility:
>
> 33221100-5544-7766-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF